# how to stay to current language while clicking a link in wpml

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am developing a multi language site with word press and wpml.

My problem is-

i have a link of a page(site.com/xyz) in a button in editor of a page which is in English. If i am in Spanish version of that page and and click that link(site.com/xyz) that goes to the English version.I want that goes to the Spanish version(site.com/es/xyz) of that page automatically instead of going to English version.(site.com/xyz).

Can anyone expert me out from it?

I hope i get some help from here. 
Thanks

Comment: Is there a cookie or something that stores the current language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below the code for link

```
$url = get_the_permalink(); 
$wpml_permalink = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $url , ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE );


<a href="<?php echo $wpml_permalink;?>">site.com/xyz</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @Vel .
That is a good tips.But my question was to translate that url autometiccaly in editor.The code you gave will return the wpml permalink. But i want to stick in the current language whenever a link is clicked.